# center DT datatable in R markdown report

Tags: r, r-markdown, dt

I have a very small table and I'm using `DT` throughout my project so I want this small table to look constant.

When using the the `width` argument in `DT::datatable()` to reduce its width, the table is left justified while centering it would look much nicer.

I've tried using `fig.align = 'center'` in the chunk options but it hasn't helped.

```
library(DT)
datatable(cars, width = 300)
```

Comment: Maybe set chunk options `results='as.is'`. This could probably be helpful: https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/rmarkdown-cheatsheet-2.0.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried that with no luck. I'm having to use the rmdformats::markdown output file and it doesn't seem to play nicely with chunk options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using `<div>` if you use HTML report:

````
<div align="center">
```{r}
library(DT)
datatable(cars, width = 300)
```
</div>
````